# How to Insert excel data with multiple row headers into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to  convert and unstructured  excel file to structured.  My headers pan across two rows (1 AND 2) For headers SKU, Qty and sales

```
   A              B                  C             D
1                                    Qty          Sales 
2   SKU             
3   2345       Nail Varnish          2              $15 
4   2346       Eye liner             3              $18
```

and my desired output once converted to dataframe should be like below

```
    SKU           Description        Qty          Sales             
0   2345         Nail Varnish         2             $15 
1   2346         Eye liner            3            $18
```

I have tried passing multiple rows as header in `read_excel` function

```
df = pd.read_excel('D:\Sales.xlsx',header=[1,2])
```

but am getting the output as

```
    Unnamed:0_level_0  Unnamed:1_level_0         Qty               Sales  
         SKU                 SKU           Unnamed:2_level_1   Unnamed:3_level_1

  0   2345             Nail Varnish             2                      $15
  1   2346             Eyeliner                 3                      $18
```

The header `SKU` is also being applied to second column. Please guide on how to go about troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the column names beforehand then you can do

```
df = pd.read_excel('D:\Sales.xlsx', header=None, names=['SKU','Description','Qty','Sales'], skiprows=2)
```

**explaination**

- `header=None` won't take default headers from excel file
- `names` will assign column names to your dataframe in order
- `skiprows` will skip first 2 rows from your excel.

Comment: Thanks Akshay, it worked, i overlooked this possibility and was trying a hard way out. Appreciate taking time to answer this